# How to upgrade libxml on CentOS

Tags: php, centos, xml, libxml

I have a following version of CentOS:

```
$ cat /etc/issue
CentOS release 5.5 (Final)
Kernel \r on an \m
```

and following version of libxml:

```
$ php -i | grep libxml
libxml Version => 2.6.26
libxml
libxml2 Version => 2.6.26
libxslt compiled against libxml Version => 2.6.26
```

and need to have newer version of libxml (primarly for usage in PHP, but obviously, it doesn't matter).

If I even install the newer version of libxml somehow:

```
wget ftp://xmlsoft.org/libxml2/libxml2-2.7.2.tar.gz
tar -xvf libxml2-2.7.2.tar.gz
cd libxml2-2.7.2
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

then I am unable to get it to work in PHP - there is still old version:

```
libxml Version => 2.6.26
libxml
libxml2 Version => 2.6.26
libxslt compiled against libxml Version => 2.6.26
```

What else do I need to do to make the new version to work with PHP?

Comment: Maybe the solution would be to find some repository with newer libxml version instead of compiling it, but I've found nothing. :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was necessary to recompile the PHP with new version of libxml. More there: https://serverfault.com/a/305682/73850

Comment: would be great if you post the solution here

Comment: The solution is linked in the answer.